# Swift Parallelism: Array vs UnsafeMutablePointer in GCD

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers, parallel-processing

I found something weird: for whatever reason, the array version of this will almost always contain random 0s after the following code runs, where as the pointer version does not.

```
var a = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: N)
//var a = [Int](repeating: 0, count: N)

let n = N / iterations

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterations) { j in
    for i in max(j * n, 1)..<((j + 1) * n) {
        a[i] = 1
    }
}

for i in max(1, N - (N % n))..<N {
    a[i] = 1
}
```

Is there a particular reason for this? I know that Swift arrays might not be consecutive in memory, but accessing the memory location with respect to each Index just once, from a single thread should not do anything too funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are not thread safe and, although they are bridged to Objective-C objects, they behave as value types with COW (copy on Write) logic.  COW on an array will make a copy of the whole array when any element changes and the reference counter is greater than 1 (conceptually, the actual implementation is a bit more subtle).

Your thread that makes changes to the array will trigger a memory copy whenever the main thread happens to reference and element.  The main thread, also makes changes so it will cause COW as well.  What you end up with is the state of the last modified copy used by either thread.  This will randomly leave some of the changes in limbo and explains the "missed" items.

To avoid this you would need to perform all changes in a specific thread and use sync() to ensure that COW on the array is only performed by that thread (this may actually reduce the number of memory copies and give better performance for very large arrays). There will be overhead and potential contention using this approach though.  It is the price to pay for thread safeness.

The other way to approach this would be to use an array of objects (referenced types).  This makes your array a simple list of pointers that are not actually changed by modifying data in the referenced objects.  although, in actual programs, you would need to mind thread safeness within each object instance, there would be far less interference (and overhead) than what you get with arrays of value types.

Comment: An array of object references is still a value, isn't it?

Comment: I thought about this as well. But then the zeroes should not be "random". Well, the OP doesn't give examples... maybe they just didn't spot the pattern.

Comment: Yes, an array of objects is contains "values" but these are "referenced type" values.  They are like pointers to the actual content.  Changing the value that is "pointed to" (the referenced value) does not require updating the pointer in the array.  For value types, COW also performs an internal indirection but the language completely hides that memory manipulation.   This may get confusing but you end up with a double indirection for value types and a triple indirection for referenced types.  Unsafe pointers in comparison are a single indirection.